# Three JS FBX Loader: model not visible in the scene No errors in the console

Tags: javascript, three.js, fbx

I am tying to render the .fbx format 3D model using THREEJS FBXLoader but the model is not visible in the scene although it is added. The variable named 'model' in which the 3D FBX model is stored is defined as I console.log it.
There are no errors in the console.

Any help regarding this will be very helpful

**Console Log Image**
[image: Console Log Image]
I console.logged the 3d model object returned from the FBXLoader, it was visible

**Scene Image**
[image: Scene Image]
In the scene, ground mesh and grid is visible but the model is not visible

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var container, controls;

container = document.getElementById('container');

var width = container.clientWidth;

var height = container.clientHeight;

var camera, scene, renderer, light;

var mixers = [];

init();
animate();

function init() {

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 0.001, 100  000 
 );
 camera.position.set( 100, 100, 100 );
 camera.up.set(0,1,0);

 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
 controls.target.set( 0, 100, 0 );
 controls.update();

 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); //0x101030
 scene.add(ambient);
 scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x1c0c4e );

 var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
 grid.material.opacity = 1;
 grid.material.transparent = true;
 scene.add( grid );

 var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
 console.log(loader);
 loader.load( 'uploaded/silly_dancing.fbx', function ( object ) {
  model = object;
  console.log(model);
  scene.add( model );
 });        


 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
 renderer.setSize( width, height);
 renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
 container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

 window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {
      
 var width = container.clientWidth;
 var height = container.clientHeight;
 camera.aspect = width / height;

 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

 renderer.setSize( width, height );
}

function animate() {

 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 render()
 controls.update();
}

function render() {

 renderer.render( scene, camera );           
}
```

Comment: have you added https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/libs/inflate.min.js ?

Comment: when you call `loader.load(url, onLoad, onProgress, onError)` be sure to pass in the `onError` argument and log the result — otherwise failure will be silent.

Comment: @gypsyCoder Yes I have added inflate.min.js file

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Ok I will add

Comment: @DonMcCurdy added the onError argument but the model is still not visible and the weird thing is that the console shows that the model is downloaded.

Comment: I have added the following script files:

    <script src="./build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/loaders/inflate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/loaders/FBXLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/loaders/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/loaders/TGALoader.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/loaders/Detector.js"></script>

Comment: People thanks for your help, It is visible now

Comment: @DhawalGaur what did you do to make the object visible?

Comment: @jao I changed the camera position. It was a very dumb mistake